# Matplotlib/Seaborn: Where am I making an elementwise comparison? ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

`toyData3` is a Pandas dataframe. `sns` is `Seaborn` module. I am able to plot the data but I get the following error when I run the code (minimal workin example) in Jupyter/Ipython console, that I don't understand. Where did I make an elementwise comparison? What is going on, and is it worth my concern?

```py
In [3]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [4]: import seaborn as sns                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [5]: data=[(0.  ,  0.        , 0.        ),(0.01,  0.10283333, 0.29774878), (0.02, -0.0395    , 0.16226045), (0.03,  0.06841667, 0.3111277 ), (0.04, -0.03508333, 0.19214552)]                                  

In [6]: toyData3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['time', 'mean', 'SD'])                                                                                                                                 

In [7]: print(toyData3)                                                                                                                                                                                            
   time      mean        SD
0  0.00  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.01  0.102833  0.297749
2  0.02 -0.039500  0.162260
3  0.03  0.068417  0.311128
4  0.04 -0.035083  0.192146

In [8]: sns.relplot(data=toyData3, x=toyData3.index, y=toyData3.loc[:, 'mean'],  kind='line')                                                                                                                      
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:122: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = op(self.values, np.asarray(other))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-35f5a3329860> in <module>
----> 1 sns.relplot(data=toyData3, x=toyData3.index, y=toyData3.loc[:, 'mean'],  kind='line')

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in relplot(x, y, hue, size, style, data, row, col, col_wrap, row_order, col_order, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, dashes, style_order, legend, kind, height, aspect, facet_kws, **kwargs)                                                                                                                              
   1693 
   1694     # Draw the plot
-> 1695     g.map_dataframe(func, x, y,
   1696                     hue=hue, size=size, style=style,
   1697                     **plot_kws)

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map_dataframe(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    829 
    830         # Finalize the annotations and layout
--> 831         self._finalize_grid(args[:2])
    832 
    833         return self

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in _finalize_grid(self, axlabels)
    852     def _finalize_grid(self, axlabels):
    853         """Finalize the annotations and layout."""
--> 854         self.set_axis_labels(*axlabels)
    855         self.set_titles()
    856         self.fig.tight_layout()

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in set_axis_labels(self, x_var, y_var)
    878         if x_var is not None:
    879             self._x_var = x_var
--> 880             self.set_xlabels(x_var)
    881         if y_var is not None:
    882             self._y_var = y_var

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in set_xlabels(self, label, **kwargs)
    889             label = self._x_var
    890         for ax in self._bottom_axes:
--> 891             ax.set_xlabel(label, **kwargs)
    892         return self
    893 

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in set_xlabel(self, xlabel, fontdict, labelpad, loc, **kwargs)
    245         elif loc == 'right':
    246             kwargs.update(x=1, horizontalalignment='right')
--> 247         return self.xaxis.set_label_text(xlabel, fontdict, **kwargs)
    248 
    249     def get_ylabel(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in set_label_text(self, label, fontdict, **kwargs)
   1561         """
   1562         self.isDefault_label = False
-> 1563         self.label.set_text(label)
   1564         if fontdict is not None:
   1565             self.label.update(fontdict)

~/anaconda3/envs/ilahi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in set_text(self, s)
   1163         if s is None:
   1164             s = ''
-> 1165         if s != self._text:
   1166             self._text = str(s)
   1167             self.stale = True

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Cannot replicate. Is there a reason data in traceback is set to toyData2 and not toyData3 ?

Comment: sorry, It's an artifact from me trying to make this example data for this post. I edited it, redoing the same stuff in Ipython console. Still getting the same error.

Comment: No worries. Still working fine on my end (IPython 7.19.0, pandas 1.2.1, numpy 1.19.5, matplotlib 3.3.4, seaborn 0.11.1). Not sure, but maybe check your lib versions in case one of them has been updated and the issue has since been fixed.

Comment: @JohanC upgraded from pandas 1.0.5 to 1.2.2. Quit jupyter and ipython. Reloaded anaconda env. Redid everything. Still getting the error. In jupyter I still get the plot but in ipython I don't. Also tried with `sns.relplot(..., x=toyData3.index.to_numpy(), ...)`. Doesn't work.

Comment: Ah I don't know why I read your seaborn as pandas and tried it with that. I updated seaborn to `0.11.1` from `0.10.1` and the error went away. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Version Issue**: I was able to replicate with `seaborn == 0.10.1`, `pandas == 1.1.4`.  But after updating to `seaborn == 0.11.1`, `pandas == 1.2.2`, I no longer get the error (I get the second plot below, hitch free).  The change is related to `seaborn`, see the patch notes for `0.11.0` within [this section](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#standardization-and-enhancements-of-data-ingest):

> `relplot()` now has the same flexibility as the axes-level functions to accept data in long- or wide-format and to accept data vectors (rather than named variables) in long-form mode.

**So updating is a good, simple solution!**  But if that isn't an option, original answer below.

---

It seems the issue is you are trying to pass actual data to the `x` and `y` arguments, rather than column names in `data`.  As seen in [examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html), the idiomatic way of plotting with `seaborn` is to name a DataFrame/array with `data` and then refer to columns in it with `x`, `y`, `hue`, etc.  This is a little different from `matplotlib` where you typically pass the *actual iterable data* to the plotting function.

So I think the easiest fix is to move your index to a new column, and then plot:

```
toyData3 = toyData3.reset_index() # creates a new column "index"
sns.relplot(data=toyData3, x='index', y='mean',  kind='line')
```

Creating the following without errors:

[image]

What highlights the issue a little more is that (in my IDE at least) your code creates the following plot before exiting:

[image]

Data looks good, but the *axis labels were not drawn*.  So it looks like `seaborn` is looking for an axis label, which would usually be provided via `x` and `y`, but in doing so runs into the error (more specifically, either the `x` or `y` is being compared to another value with a `==`, returning an array of boolean values rather than a single `True` or `False`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!